# Функция срабатывает только для первого элемента .textfill

Tags: jquery

Я использую плагин [jQuery TextFill](https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill/), чтобы изменять размер текста.
Всё работает, как нужно, но срабатывает только для первого элемента таблицы:

```js
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.customToggler = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#textfill-departments-title").textfill({ maxFontPixels: 0 });
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Нужно, чтобы работало для каждой строки. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#textfill-departments-title")
```

идентификатор элемента html всегда уникален и обращение идет только к **первому** элементу, имеющему данный идентификатор

если вам требуется применить какую-то функцию ко всем выбранным элементам - используйте классы

```
$(".textfill-departments-title")
```

правда пропишите это в ваших элементах типа

```
<div class = 'textfill-departments-title'>...</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!